# Vulcanization breaks Polymer code (Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function)

Tags: javascript, performance, polymer

I have single page app in Polymer. Everything works works great but when I vulcanize it I always get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on many places of Polymer's default code. But after all my app still works. But I cannot see any paper toast after clicking on "Register" button in `<my-register-box>` element.

My `index.html` look like this:

```
<head>
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
....
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-scaffold/core-scaffold.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-animated-pages/transitions/slide-from-right.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/flatiron-director/flatiron-director.html">
....
<link rel="import" href="register-box.html">
...
</head>

<body>
...
<my-register-box name="{{name}}" email="{{email}}" url="{{url}}"></my-register-box>
...
```

And `register-box.html` like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icon/core-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input-decorator.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">

<polymer-element name="my-register-box" attributes="name email url">
    <template>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
        <script src="jsencrypt.min.js"></script>
        <paper-input-decorator label="Enter your name" floatingLabel error="Required">
            <input is="core-input" id="form_name" required>
        </paper-input-decorator>

        ...

        <paper-toast id="formTermsToast" text="You must agree with temrs"></paper-toast>
        <paper-toast id="formValidToast" text="Form is not valid"></paper-toast>
        ....

        <paper-fab id="fab" icon="check" title="Register"
                   on-click="{{register}}"></paper-fab>
    </template>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Polymer({
            name: '?',
            email: '?',
            url: '?',
            autoValidate: false,
            valid: false,
            observe: {
                '$.form_name.validity.valid': 'validate',
                '$.form_email.validity.valid': 'validate',
                '$.form_sa_uname.validity.valid': 'validate',
                '$.form_sa_pass.validity.valid': 'validate',
                '$.formTerms.checked': 'validate'
            },
            validate: function() {
                this.valid = true;
                if((!this.readyState) || (!this.autoValidate))
                    return;
                var $d = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('paper-input-decorator');
                var th = this;
                Array.prototype.forEach.call($d, function(d) {
                    d.isInvalid = !d.querySelector('input').validity.valid;
                    if(d.isInvalid) {
                        th.$.formValidToast.show();
                        th.valid = false;
                    }
                });

                if(!this.$.formTerms.checked) {
                    this.$.formTermsToast.show();
                    this.valid = false;
                }
            },
            registerEmail: function() {
                ...
            },
            register: function() {
                this.autoValidate = true;
                this.validate();
                ...
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

My vulcanization:

```
vulcanize --inline index.html
```

I get that error for example here (after calling {{register}})

```
....
renderOpened: function() {
      this.notifyResize(); //Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
....
```

but it's not even my code :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this exact same problem with the --csp option in the latest build of Polymer and Vulcanize.

It's related to the new resizer mixin that was recently introduced, and how that gets vulcanized. For some reason the mixin is rendered at the bottom of the page and that causes problems.

It's the function block that starts as follows:

```
(function (scope) {

/**
  `Polymer.CoreResizable` and `Polymer.CoreResizer` are a set of mixins that can be used
  in Polymer elements to coordinate the flow of resize events between "resizers" (elements
  that control the size or hidden state of their children) and "resizables" (elements that
  need to be notified when they are resized or un-hidden by their parents in order to take
  action on their new measurements).

  Elements that perform measurement should add the `Core.Resizable` mixin to their 
  Polymer prototype definition and listen for the `core-resize` event on themselves.
  This event will be fired when they become showing after having been hidden,
  when they are resized explicitly by a `CoreResizer`, or when the window has been resized.
  Note, the `core-resize` event is non-bubbling.

  `CoreResizable`'s must manually call the `resizableAttachedHandler` from the element's
  `attached` callback and `resizableDetachedHandler` from the element's `detached`
  callback.

    @element CoreResizable
    @status beta
    @homepage github.io
*/

scope.CoreResizable = {

... [rest of code block here] ...

}
```

Move this piece of code to the top of your script block (it's referenced by the paper-toast), and it should work. I'm assuming that this will probably be corrected in an upcoming release of Vulcanize.

Comment: In my case updating to latest build of Polymer and Vulcanize solved the problem. But moving of that piece of code ought to solve my previous issue too.

Comment: I just updated today and also solved my issue - however yesterday it was still failing! Just bad timing I guess.

Comment: @bittebbytailfly What version are you using?  I am running into the same issue.  I am using vulcanizer 0.7.9 and most recent masters for all polymer pulls.

Comment: @Goblinlord - I seem to also be getting it again now, but not on all code I try to vulcanize. It's clearly related to the way controls are nested. I've been using the same version I think, and it works without the CSP flag but not with. I even tried running it without CSP and then rerunning on the output file but it didn't work. I have found a workaround though, and that was to put the paper-toast in the <head> of the top level page (see here: https://github.com/bittenbytailfly/deadbolt-password-generator-chrome-mobile-app/blob/master/app/deadbolt.htm) - it's not pretty, but it worked for me!

Comment: @bittenbytailfly Excellent ^^ I will have to try that out this weekend